# multiplication of all the combination of elements in certain dimension

Tags: python, pytorch, batch-processing, multiplication

I'm trying to do multiplication of all the combination of elements in a certain dimension.
For example,
using for loops it would be

```
for a,i in enumerate(A):
    for b,j in enumerate(B):
        c[i][j] = a[1]*b[0]
```

not using for loop would be

```
A[:,None,1]*B[:,0]
```

this worked fine for 2-dimensions(A.shape=(4,2),B.shape=(4,2)).

However, When I am expanding above procedures to 3-dimensions(A.shape=(2,4,2),B.shape=(2,4,2)).

I tried with

```
A[:,:,1]*B[:,:,None,0]
```

but gives me an error.

How can I do this without using for loops???

For 2-dimensional tensors this is what I get

```
a = torch.FloatTensor([[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0,4]])
b = torch.FloatTensor([[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0]])
c = a[:,None,0] * b[:,1]

print(c)

tensor([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
        [ 2.,  4.,  6.,  8.],
        [ 3.,  6.,  9., 12.],
        [ 4.,  8., 12., 16.]])
```

but in the case of

```
A = torch.cat([a.unsqueeze(0),a.unsqueeze(0)],dim=0)
B = torch.cat([b.unsqueeze(0),b.unsqueeze(0)],dim=0)


C = A[:,:,None,0] * B[:,:,1] << RuntimeError

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (4) must match the size of tensor b (2) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

what I want is

```
tensor([[[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
         [ 2.,  4.,  6.,  8.],
         [ 3.,  6.,  9., 12.],
         [ 4.,  8., 12., 16.]],

        [[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
         [ 2.,  4.,  6.,  8.],
         [ 3.,  6.,  9., 12.],
         [ 4.,  8., 12., 16.]]])
```

I cannot think of a way to do this without using for loop in dimension 0.

Comment: Please, always post the error message and the whole stacktrace.

Comment: @Sukwon, could you show a small table, e.g. 3x3 clarifying what do you exactly want to compute?

Comment: BTW, your first example is simply the outer product of specific cols: `torch.outer(A[:, 1], B[:, 0])`. What would be the expected output shape for 3 dimensions? `(2, 4, 2, 4)`?

Comment: @aerijman added example!

Comment: @Berriel I expect output shape of (2,4,4,1)